# Knitr pdf not working on Mac OS X error "! Missing $ inserted."

Tags: pdftex, r, knitr, markdown

I have the following chunk in rmarkdown

```
{r }
library(psych)
a  <- (matrix(c(1:1000), ncol=4))
f <- fa(a)
```

But when I try to print inline the following output:

```
`r f$null.chisq`
```

I get the following error message and no pdf is generated

```
/usr/local/bin/pandoc +RTS -K512m -RTS prova2.utf8.md --to latex
--from markdown+autolink_bare_uris+ascii_identifiers+tex_math_single_backslash-implicit_figures
--output prova2.pdf --template /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.2/Resources/library/rmarkdown/rmd/latex/default-1.14.tex
--highlight-style tango --latex-engine /Library/TeX/texbin/pdflatex --variable 'geometry:margin=1in'

! Missing $ inserted. <inserted text> 
                $ l.162 1.6708458\times

pandoc: Error producing PDF from TeX source Error: pandoc document
conversion failed with error 43 Execution halted
```

I tested the same exact code on a Windows machine and it works fine, but it does not on my Mac, meaning I am aware that this error might not be fully reproducible.
Also, I do not even have line 162 on the file where I saved the script for the reproducible error, so I am having a hard time understanding what that

```
$ l.162
```

actually means.

However, if I omit the last line of code, i.e.

```
`r f$null.chisq`
```

then everything works fine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add `$$` around the number, which was written out in scientific notation by **knitr**.

```
$`r f$null.chisq`$
```

Comment: Thank you it worked. Which is the meaning of embedding a number in dollar signs? Why is the notation `r` insufficient in this case?

Comment: `r` returns something like `a \times 10^b`, which has to be included in a math environment `$ $`